# Enter button dosn't calculate

Tags: microsoft-excel

In MS Excel the ENTER BUTTON when pressed isn't adding up the calculation, example  =2+2 enter  what happens is the next cell is high lighted Please can you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the cell continues to show the formula when you hit ENTER and not the results of the formula, you may have unintentionally set the cell to display the formula instead of the results.

1) Check the formatting of the cell. Be sure the cell is not formatted as text.

2) Highlight the cell and check the characters in the formula bar. If there is a single apostrophe in front of the formula, remove that character.

3) Go to Formulas>Formula Auditing and be sure Show Formulas is not turned on.

For more information and a great Excel resource website, visit: http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/04/12/excel-formulas-are-not-working/